# Axis2 - Undeclared namespace prefix "soapenv"

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

does anyone know how to solve the following problem when calling stub which is generated by the axis2 1.7.5 (Wsdl2Java)?

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "soapenv"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,56]
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:508)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:368)
```

I found that the stub sent the following request without adding/defining the SOAP version (xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/") which causes the problem

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>....</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As therefore, i tried to set the SoapVersionURL as follows

```
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setSoapVersionURI(org.apache.axis2.namespace.Constants.URI_SOAP11_ENV);
```

or even directly set the namespace in the stub as

```
envelope.declareNamespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "soapenv")
```

However, both methods still ignore the "xmlns:soapenv" namespace and causes the undefined prefix "soapenv".

If i make the request in the SoapUI, i can see the Soap Version in the request as follows

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        ...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think it may be my axis2 / wsdl2Java setting problems

please kindly help. Thank alot.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using Axis2 1.7.9 and Axiom 1.2.22.

Stepping through with a debugger, the namespace was being set correctly on the envelope but lost during serialization.  In my case it was using com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl, and something seems to be going wrong within that implementation.

I fixed this by adding woodstox-core and stax2-api to my classpath.  These libraries provide an alternate XMLStreamWriter implementation that appears to be more reliable.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's something related with version 1.7.* of axis2 for this specific envelope problem.
I have solved this issue using axis2-1.6.2 for generate client.
You can download axis2-1.6.* version [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/axis/axis2/java/core/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)